# calculate KL-divergence from sampling

Tags: it.information-theory

Assume we have two sampling process, i.e. we can draw samples from two (not explicitly known) distributions P and Q. Is there any simple way to calculate the KL-divergence D(P||Q)? P and Q could be discrete or continuous.

Comment: This answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211175/kullback-leibler-divergence/248657#248657  and references therein is relevant.

Answer (score 4):

The whole paper here is on that topic

[cosmal.ucsd.edu/~gert/papers/isit_2010.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20130305001428/http://cosmal.ucsd.edu/~gert/papers/isit_2010.pdf)

Comment: The linked paper does not address the original question of two-sample estimation of KL-divergence, but its references [3]-[5] may.

Currently the link is dead.  I have submitted an edit to update it to https://web.archive.org/web/20130305001428/http://cosmal.ucsd.edu/~gert/papers/isit_2010.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link is more stable? http://eceweb.ucsd.edu/~gert/papers/isit_2010.pdf